# jQuery multiple animate() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate a set of elements simultaneously (almost, there's a small delay between each animation):

```
$('.block').each(function(i){
   $(this).stop().delay(60 * i).animate({
     'opacity': 1
   }, {
      duration: 250,
      complete: mycallbackfunction // <- this fires the callback on each animation :(
   });
});
```

How can I run a callback function after all animations have completed?

Comment: you can have each individual anim. increment a value, and if that value is = number of animations, then run the actual function

Comment: is there a reason you can't call mycallbackfunction after the entire $(".block").each statement? or am i misunderstanding your code?

Comment: yes. If I do that, the function will be executed right away. I want to wait for the animations to finish, then execute it

Comment: Have a separate callback for the last animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a closure around a counter variable.

```
var $blocks = $('.block');
var count = $blocks.length;
$blocks.each(function(i){
   $(this).stop().delay(60 * i).animate({
     'opacity': 1
   }, {
      duration: 250,
      complete: function() {
        if (--count == 0) {
          // All animations are done here!
          mycallbackfunction();
        }
      }
   });
});
```

Note the saving of the list of items into the $block variable to save a lookup.

Comment: just do the decrement in `myCallbackFn()`... but ya this is the only answer I see

Comment: In order to do the decrement in `mycallbackfunction()`, it needs to be defined in the same scope as `count`. The OP's example didn't show where `mycallbackfunction()` was defined.

Comment: thanks! this seems to work :D but you have a mistake: it should be `if (count == 0) mycallbackfunction();`

Comment: ps: do you know how can I decrement and check `count` at the same time?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to run `mycallbackfunction` every time, and something else the last time. My Bad!

Comment: You can do it like this: if (--count == 0) { ...}

Answer (score 4):

Since jQuery 1.5, you can use [`$.when` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), which is a bit easier to write and understand:

```
var $blocks = $('.block');

$blocks.each(function(i){
   $(this).stop().delay(60 * i).animate({
     'opacity': 1
   }, {
      duration: 250
   });
});

$.when($blocks).then(mycallbackfunction);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zqfdq/)

Comment: That will trigger the callback even if the animations were stopped via `.stop()`.

Answer (score 4):

[Felix Kling's answer](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2011/02/14/jquery-fadeout-lot-fadein-deferred-promises-jqueryanimate/) will fire the callback when there's no animation left to do. This makes the callback firing **even** if the animation is **stopped** via  `$el.stop()` and thus not completed to the end.

I found an [method by Elf Sternberg](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2011/02/14/jquery-fadeout-lot-fadein-deferred-promises-jqueryanimate/) using deferred objects which I implemented in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8v6nZ/

Answer (score 1):

```
   var block = $('.block');
   block.each(function(i){
   $(this).stop().delay(60 * i).animate({
     'opacity': 1
    }, {
      duration: 250,
      complete: i== (block.length-1) ? myCallbackFunction : function(){}
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.block').each(function(i){
   $(this).stop().delay(60 * i).animate({
     'opacity': 1
   }, {
      duration: 250,
      complete: ((i == $('.block').length - 1) ? mycallbackfunction : null)
   });
});
```