# Hide multiple elements with jQuery and get one callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is pretty straightforward. If I select two or more elements with jQuery and, for example, use jQuery's fadeOut() function to hide them, the callback function is invoked twice (for each element). Is there a way to only receive one callback?

The code I am currently using to perform this task is pasted below.

```
$('#element-1, #element-2').fadeOut( 250, function() { /* Callback invoked twice. */ });
```

A similar question has been posted before ([jQuery multiple animate() callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823403/jquery-multiple-animate-callback)), but the solution seems quite complicated for what seems a simple problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`$.when` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) ([deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)):

```
$.when($('#element-1, #element-2').fadeOut(250)).then(function() {
    // do something
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/da2ah/)

This works with any animation afaik.

Comment: Are there any other way? it looks so walk-around-ishly... Or is to be regarded as a proper way in jQuery and it's only my ignorance that objects?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way and the `.animate` documentation does not mention anything either.