# jQuery multiple callbacks to one callback counting calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I need just one callback at the and of multiple callbacks. With a simple "class"  MultiCallback that count the calls it seems to be solved. 
But the fadeIn function of jQuery calls mCallback just once.**

It have to call mCallback 3 times. That happens by using a callback function directly inside top scope.

Tested my MultiCallback class also on my own functions without any problems. I know
there a other ways like [Hide multiple elements with jQuery and get one callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378349/hide-multiple-elements-with-jquery-and-get-one-callback)...
Just wanna know what is wrong with my logic.

```
<div id="1" style="display: none; background-color: green;"></div>
<div id="2" style="display: none; background-color: red;"></div>
<div id="3" style="display: none; background-color: blue;"></div>

<script>

    var allElements = "#1, #2, #3";
    var multiCallback = new MultiCallback( $(allElements).length, function()
            {
                console.log("NEVER ENTER CALLBACK");
            });
    $(allElements).fadeIn(400, multiCallback.mCallback());

    function MultiCallback(limit, fn)
    {
        var finishedCalls = 0;

        function mCallback()
        {
            // Just enter one time !
            if (++finishedCalls == limit)
            {
                fn();
            }
        }

        return {
            mCallback : mCallback
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your aim is to fade the divs one at time in succession?

Comment: Mind that you ARE calling three callbacks, but they are executed at the same time. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @Cranio yes i want to fade all 3 divs at the same time. is there something like "lock" in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
// executes function, returns undefined, passing undefined
$(allElements).fadeIn(400, multiCallback.mCallback());
```

to

```
// pass a reference to the function
$(allElements).fadeIn(400, multiCallback.mCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. replace multiCallback.mCallback() to  multiCallback.mCallback
2. place your code inside `$(function(){ ... });` since DOM elements may be unavailable at that moment.

[fixed code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjWwm/1/)