# jQuery: Matching multiple elements but having it perform only a single animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Description of Problem ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8ZuW/)):

I'm attempting to match all elements and have them fade out simultaneously whenever any of them are clicked. The problem this creates is that the target I'm using will trigger three times, invoking three `alert();` calls. I want them all to fade at once, and I'd prefer not to use a wrapper.

How can I ensure that everything inside the `fadeOut()` completion fires only a single time?

### Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="things">
    <div id="one"></div>
</div>
<div class="things">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
<div class="things">
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var triggerCount = 0;
$('.things').mousedown(function() {
    $('.things').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        triggerCount++;
        alert('fading '+triggerCount+' time(s)');
    });
});
```

Comment: :O .. I don't think, we can do this without wrapper.

Comment: Look at the answer described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7378365/1608705. If you don't want to use jQuery.when(), you should create a wrapper element.

Comment: @annemartijn Awesome! .when() is what I was looking for. Add it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the answer described here: [Hide multiple elements with jQuery and get one callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378365/1608705). If you don't want to use [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), you should create a wrapper element.

How to use [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```js
$.when($('.things').fadeOut(250)).then(function() {
    // do something
    alert('fading');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)**:

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more
>   objects, usually deferred objects that represent asynchronous events

```
var triggerCount = 0;
$('.things').mousedown(function () {
    $.when($('.things').fadeOut(2000)).then(function () {
        triggerCount++;
        alert('fading '+triggerCount+' time(s)');
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8ZuW/3/)**

Comment: Greatly appreciate the assistance, sir, but I have to give it to @annemartijn for putting in the comments quicker.