# How to reduce nested callbacks in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been tasked with rewriting this terrible piece of code which is meant to sequentially fade in layers on a map (they are all transparent pngs) on a web page. It needs to operate in a sequence, then loop back to the start where no layers are visible, and fade back in one at a time. This sequence should repeat itself forever.

I'm not really sure what the most recommended way of doing this is in javascript and interested what stack overflow has to say.

There has to be a better way than this! Am interested in pros/cons of any methods.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $("#layer-1").fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $("#layer-2").fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $("#layer-3").fadeIn(1000, function() {
          $("#layer-4").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $("#layer-5").fadeIn(1000, function() {
              $("#layer-6").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $("#layer-7").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                  $("#layer-8").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    // pause for 2 seconds, then reset and hide all layers:
                    $("#home-map .layer").delay(2000).fadeOut();
                  });
                });
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }, 10000)
```

Edit: The reason I think this is different to other answers is because I was trying to set things up in an infinite loop, as well as chaining the animations. There are lots of approaches to solving callback hell in javascript and its a very common sticking point, so no doubt there will be similar questions.

Comment: Using promises :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Yep, promises would be a great approach to help mitigate some of this.  You could also probably handle a lot of this as a loop as the order of layers seems pretty regular.

Comment: I tried writing a recursive function but got stuck... had it figured out logically in my head but ran into weirdness... when you do .fadeOut("slow", callback) on multiple items, and use the callback, it starts e.g. 8 new calls to the recursive function... I think. Javascript hurts my head!

Comment: Promises are the wrong approach here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198091/chaining-jquery-animations-that-affect-different-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining jQuery animations that affect different elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198091/chaining-jquery-animations-that-affect-different-elements)

Comment: This is the well-known... CALLBACK HELL! :P

Comment: Yes, I am aware this is callback hell! :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Challenge accepted... using an recursive approach.

```
(function main(index){
   if(index >= 9){
     return $.when($("#home-map .layer").delay(2000).fadeOut()).then(function(){
         main(1); //restart
     });
   }
  $("#layer-"+index).fadeIn(1000, function(){
         main(index+1);
  });
 })(1);
```

http://jsbin.com/rurokipipi/1/edit?output

Comment: this is very similar to what I had (deleted my code or I'd have posted it), in practice the callback of fadeOut() seemed to be firing once per layer (each element matched by the selector)... I may be wrong but that's what it seemed like was happening

+1 for pure recursive approach though

Comment: @mike-source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378349/hide-multiple-elements-with-jquery-and-get-one-callback

Comment: rewarding this top answer as it is in my opinion the best, @yivo's answer is essentially similar but probably a bit easier to follow and doesn't rely on when/then (something I wasn't aware existed)

Comment: @mike-source thanks ;) ( didnt know either, just quickly looked it up...)

Answer (score 7):

By using async await + promises

if you call `.promise()` after a animation you will get a promise back. thanks to it you can be able to wait for it to finish

```
async function animate() {
    await $("#layer-1").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    await $("#layer-2").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    await $("#layer-3").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    await $("#layer-4").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    await $("#layer-5").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    await $("#layer-6").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    await $("#layer-7").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    await $("#layer-8").fadeIn(1000).promise()
    // pause for 2 seconds, then reset and hide all layers:
    await $("#home-map .layer").delay(2000).fadeOut().promise();
}

const loop = () => animate().then(loop)
loop()
```

Looking at this makes a for loop fit in very well.

```
async function animate() {
    for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        await $(`#layer-${i}`).fadeIn(1000).promise()

    // pause for 2 seconds, then reset and hide all layers:
    await $("#home-map .layer").delay(2000).fadeOut();
}
```

This is only possible in most recent browser

---

Guessing it can be made more dynamic if you did

```
for (let layer of $("#home-map .layer"))
    await $(layer).fadeIn(1000).promise()
```

---

Here is a es5 alternativ to same problem but using reduce to chain promises

```js
function animate() {
  $(".layer").toArray().reduce(function(prev, elm){
    return prev.then(function(){
      return $(elm).fadeIn(1000).promise();
    })
  }, Promise.resolve()).then(function(){
    // do the master
    $(".masterLayer").delay(2000).fadeOut();
  })
}

animate()
```

```css
.layer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masterLayer">
  <div class="layer">layer 1</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 2</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 3</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 4</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 5</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer for those who can use `async`/`await`. For those who can't, I recommend `queue`, which is certainly more verbose but results in essentially the same calling order

Answer (score 6):

use a class instead of ids, then loop through them and add delay based on their index

```js
var layers = $(".layer").length;

function foreverLoop() {

  $(".masterLayer").show();
  $(".layer").hide();

  $(".layer").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(1000);
  });
  
  $(".masterLayer").delay(1000*layers + 2000).fadeOut(1000);
  
  setTimeout("foreverLoop()", 1000*layers + 3000 + 500);
}

foreverLoop();
```

```css
.layer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masterLayer">
  <div class="layer">layer 1</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 2</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 3</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 4</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 5</div>
  <div class="layer">layer 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `fadeOut` for all layers as author requested.

Comment: @yivo added in the fadeOut of all of them

Comment: it doesn't loop

Comment: @mike-source with looping. i thought you wanted a proof of concept alternative to callback hell, not to create the whole solution

Comment: ok, not a bad solution either now sorry for not making that clear! I was most interested in how to restart the sequence. was trying to understand if the fact it needed looping would mean one solution to callback hell was better in this situation than another, i dont think it matters too much. this is a suitable answer too.

Comment: @mike-source, fair enough. as an fyi, the solution you chose (and a lot of the other solutions) are dependent on the number of layers, and the code would need to be tweaked if that number of layers changes. just something to take note of. typically, its best practice to make code (in this situation) more general so its more maintainable and adaptable. i would suggest that whichever approach you take, that you code in such a way that its not dependent on having a specific number of layers.

Comment: interesting... if you can convince me of why yours would scale better I'd be willing to change the accepted answer, if you're only referring to using .length to measure the number of layers, I think I would just incorporate that into the recursive answer if needed

the reason I prefer recursion and callbacks over 'guessing' an interval for setTimeout to retrigger is because in practice I've found JS 'internal clock' to be unreliable, always better to wait for a callback before starting something else... I hope that makes sense?

Best not to rely on something unreliable.

Comment: (I understand you aren't really 'guessing', its just with javascript on the web, you'll find 1000ms might sometimes happen at 999ms or 1001ms... maybe its just me that thinks this)

Comment: @mike-source your reasoning is sound and i wouldnt sway you otherwise in terms of approach preferences. the note on maintainable/adaptable code was for your benefit in current and future coding projects (since in the code you initially posted seemed to also be based on a specific number of layers). it'll save you future time and effort as your code and specs change (as they often do).

Answer (score 3):

```js
var MAX_LAYER_NUMBER        = 8;
var LAYER_FADE_IN_DURATION  = 1000;
var LAYER_FADE_OUT_DURATION = 1000;
var LAYER_FADE_IN_OUT_DELAY = 2000;

function fadeInLayer(layerNumber, done) {
  if (layerNumber <= MAX_LAYER_NUMBER) {
    $('#layer-' + layerNumber).stop(true, true).fadeIn(LAYER_FADE_IN_DURATION, function() {
      done(layerNumber);
      fadeInLayer(layerNumber + 1, done);
    });
  }
}

function fadeInOutLayers() {
  fadeInLayer(1, function(layerNumber) {
    if (layerNumber === MAX_LAYER_NUMBER) {
      $(".layer").delay(LAYER_FADE_IN_OUT_DELAY).fadeOut(LAYER_FADE_OUT_DURATION);
    }
  });
}


$(function() {
  fadeInOutLayers();
  setInterval(fadeInOutLayers, LAYER_FADE_IN_DURATION * MAX_LAYER_NUMBER + LAYER_FADE_IN_OUT_DELAY + LAYER_FADE_OUT_DURATION)
});
```

```css
.layer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer-1" class="layer">layer-1</div>
<div id="layer-2" class="layer">layer-2</div>
<div id="layer-3" class="layer">layer-3</div>
<div id="layer-4" class="layer">layer-4</div>
<div id="layer-5" class="layer">layer-5</div>
<div id="layer-6" class="layer">layer-6</div>
<div id="layer-7" class="layer">layer-7</div>
<div id="layer-8" class="layer">layer-8</div>
```

Comment: I got about this far... is the only way to make this loop to call setInterval() on fadeInOutLayers()?

Comment: @mike-source Hi. I have updated answer: added code snippets and setInterval.

Comment: probably what I'm going to go with as this is close to my first attempt and feels the most intuitive to me... i'm just struggling to explain it to my students! need to sit down with a coffee and pick it apart for bit, thanks though!

Comment: @mike-source Please ask. I will help you :)

Comment: where you've used `done(layerNumber);` is this a way to access the callback function passed to fadeInLayer in the fadeInOutLayers function? i think that's what i was missing or getting confused with

Comment: the problem I had was that the last instruction in the sequence was `$('.layer').fadeOut(), which asynchronously fires on all 8 layers, if you use the callback from fadeOut() to retrigger the initial function, it will start 8 new processes and continue exponentially until memory runs out

Comment: so better control of/passing the callback is necessary... am assuming @yivo just knew this was better practice anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a recurring series of asynchronous function calls. You *could* use promises to [flatten your arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/), but we're not talking about code that we expect to throw errors, so there's no need of asynchronous `try..catch`, which is what promises are.

Asynchronous functions that happen in sequence are queues. jQuery has a nice [`queue` method](http://api.jquery.com/queue), which is what I recommend here.

Now, because you're executing this queue on a variety of different elements, you'll need to pick a common element to store the core queue on. In this case, I'll use `body` but you could use pretty much any element (I recommend the closest common parent to all of the elements that you're animating because it will allow you to use the structure on the page in multiple places without the queues interfering with one-another, but that's more of an advanced step).

The `fx` queue is the default queue, which is where animations actually occur. We're going to want to manage this queue separately from the `fx` queue so that other animations can happen alongside this queue.

```
function myAnimation() {
  $('body')
    // queue up the next step of the animation
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      // `next` is a function that tells the queue to continue
      // on to the next step. We pass next to the complete
      // callback of the animation so that they can continue
      // fluidly.
      $('#player-1').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-2').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-3').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-3').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-4').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-5').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-6').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-7').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#player-8').fadeIn(1000, next);
    })
    // here we want to wait for a bit before continuing with
    // the rest of the queue
    .delay(2000, 'my-animation')
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      $('#home-map .layer').fadeOut(next);
    })
    // here we repeat the animation so that a `setInterval` call
    // is unnecessary, and so that we don't have to care how long
    // the animation takes in total
    .queue('my-animation', (next) => {
      // queue up the next iteration of the animation
      myAnimation();
      // continue with the queued animation
      next();
    });
}

myAnimation(); // queue up the animation
$('body').dequeue('my-animation'); // start the animation
```

Now, this code is awfully repetitive. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to change it to a simple `for` loop or whatever you'd like it to be. It's just an example of the overall simplification.

The code in this example is longer than the original, but don't let that fool you. Because it's a queue, it's easier to reason about and edit later. Steps can be inserted and removed without needing to change wait times or attempt to rebalance nested parenthesis/curly braces.

Comment: thanks for this answer, probably not the way I would approach it but this is why i love stack overflow! I'm sure knowing this will come in handy sooner or later.

Comment: Instead of queue you could do `$('#player-2').fadeIn.promise().then(() => $('#player-3').fadeIn.promise()).then(...)`

Comment: you could. `promise` will wait for the entire `fx` queue on the node to complete before firing. There are some implications there that could cause issues if you want multiple animations on the same node simultaneously. With that said, if you need that much control, you probably shouldn't use jQuery, and instead would want to try something like [GSAP](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/).